# Multiple marker is not showing on google map

Tags: javascript, php, sql, google-maps-markers

I am new in webdeveloping. For my thesis project I have to use marker on google map. I am trying to fetch latitude and longitude from sql database and using jason parsing and JS I am trying to put multiple markers on the google map. but the marker is not showing on the map. I don't understand where is my error. please let me know the solution. the full code is below.

` <?php
require_once('data_inject/db_connect.php');
$db = new DbConnect();

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM potholes";
$data = mysqli_query($db->getDb(), $sql);

foreach ($data as $key)
{
            $locations[]=array( 'name'=>'Potholes', 'lat'=>$key['lat_p'], 'lng'=>$key['longi_p'] );
}
/* Convert data to json */
$markers = json_encode( $locations );
```

?>

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php
        echo "var markers=$markers;\n";
    ?>

    function initMap() {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.7654627,90.4373187); // default location
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var json=JSON.parse( markers );
        length = json.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        
        {
            var data = json[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: data.name
            });

           
            (function(marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.name);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });


            })(marker, data);

      }
    }
    </script>
         
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Any error in dev console? Have you seen what you have in `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
<?php
    echo "var markers=$markers;\n";
?>
```

Since `$markers` is JSON, you don't need to parse it. Replace

```
var json=JSON.parse( markers );
```

with

```
var json = markers;
```

As for the `infoWindow`s, add

```
let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

before setting the content.